# How to kill a nodejs spawned process (ng serve) with its children?

Tags: node.js, angular, spawn

I'm trying to spawn 'ng serve' using node's child_process library and when I'm killing the process (running on windows) it only kills the main shell leaving node server running. I tried many solutions including 'taskkill', grouping processes and libraries like tree-kill but none of them work. I wanted to know if there's something specific to kill a process like this?

I created a simple angular app using `ng new test-app` and used script bellow just to isolate the things:

```
const spawn = require('child_process').spawn;

function main() {
  const serverProcess = spawn('ng.cmd', [ 'serve' ], { shell: true });
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log('Killing...', serverProcess.pid);
    spawn('taskkill', ["/pid", serverProcess.pid, '/f', '/t']);
    // process.kill(serverProcess.pid);
  }, 5000);
}

setTimeout(main);
```

*I'm using **ng.cmd** ...because windows*

If you try to run you'll see in task explorer that it kills the shell but the server is still running on background.

Comment: try `serverProcess.kill('SIGHUP');` as illustrated at https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_subprocess_kill_signal

Comment: Hi @Andriy, I tried but I think that windows doesn't recognize 'SIGHUP'.

Comment: SIGHUP wouldn't work anyway. HANGUP means *"Hangup detected on controlling terminal or death of controlling process" - you want to send SIGTERM or SIGKILL. But so far, I haven't found a way to kill the sub-process that `ng serve` starts. Either signal will kill `ng serve` itself, but the child *of that child* stays open and holds onto its port. Maddening.